# Implementations of (fully) dynamic connectivity data structures

Tags: dynamic, graph-theory

The [dynamic connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity) problem for graphs consists in maintaining a graph data structure that allows for adding and deleting edges of the graph.
Moreover, the data structure should support connectivity queries.
Typically, such a query is of the form ''Are the nodes u and v connected in the graph?''
There are variants of the dynamic connectivity problem that also support different connectivity queries like [2-edge-connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph) or [biconnectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component).

My question is: Are there existing efficient implementations of dynamic connectivity data structures?
By efficient I mean that data structures with a low amortized operation costs.
In particular, I am NOT interested in trivial implementations with a complexity of O(n) per operation!
Below I describe in more detail what I am looking for an what I already know.

If only edge insertions are allowed the dynamic connectivity problem can be solved by the well known [disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) (aka union find) data structure.
For this data structure there are implementations available in many different programming languages.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case for the dynamic connectivity problem that also allows edge deletions.
The situation is even worse for data structures that also allow other connectivity queries like 2-edge- or biconnectivity.

To the best of my knowledge the algorithms presented in [Holm et al. (2001)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/502090.502095) are still state of the art for many dynamic connectivity problems.
This publication was accompanied by an experimental [study](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/945394.945398), however, as far as I can tell the code was never made publicly available. Also, therein only implementations for the regular connectivity problem are discussed, not for 2-edge- or biconnectivity.

The algorithms by Holm et al. (and also by other authors) are highly non-trivial.
Even though the algorithms are described in much detail it requires a lot of expertise to implement these algorithms in practice.
Because of this I am looking for existing implementation of different dynamic connectivity data structures.
The table below summarizes the (currently underwhelming) implementations of different combinations of supported manipulations and queries.

| Graph Manipulations | Connectivity | 2-edge-connectivity | Biconnectivity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| incremental (adding edges) | [disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#External_links) |  |  |
| decremental (deleting edges) | [Rafael Glikis](https://github.com/rafaelglikis/dynamic-connectivity) |  |  |
| fully (adding and deleting edges) |  |  |  |

I have searched for implementations in different places. I have looked on git-hub, I have looked through the external links in the relevant Wikipedia articles and I have skimmed through a lot of literature without any success.

Comment: I edited the question. I am looking for implementations with small amortized cost per operation. For example, Holm et al (2001) present a data structure with amortized operation cost of O(log^2 n).

Answer (score 0):

I expect we will need a framework for trying things out so that we can discuss this in concrete terms.

I have implemented a small windows application that accepts user queries to read, build, edit and query the connectivity of a graph, showing the time taken to execute each.

Sample run:

```
Supported queries
add v1 v2 :     add link to graph
delete v1 v2 :  remove link from graph
reach src dst : find path between vertices
read filepath : input graph links from file
help :          this help display


type query> read ../dat/3elt.graph.seq.txt

4720 vertices 27444 edges

raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        0.539246        0.539246    query

type query> delete 23 20

4720 vertices 27443 edges

raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        0.004432        0.004432    query
       
type query> add 23 20

4720 vertices 27444 edges

raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        0.0046639       0.0046639   query
```

The complete application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/graphConnectivity

To demonstrate how this application can be used, I built it with the graph engine at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinderFeb2023 and ran it on a couple of the test datasets from https://dyngraphlab.github.io/

| dataset | edge count | delete | add |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3elt.graph.seq.txt | 27,443 | 5ms | 5ms |
| 144.graph.seq.txt | 2,148,787 | 13ms | 13ms |

To get the average time to perform multiple queries, use the random command, like this:

```
Supported queries
add v1 v2 :     add link to graph
add random n :  add n random links to graph
delete v1 v2 :  remove link from graph     
reach src dst : find path between vertices 
read filepath : input graph links from file
help :          this help display

type query> read ../dat/3elt.graph.seq.txt

4720 vertices 27444 edges

type query> add random 10 

4720 vertices 27454 edges 

raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
      10        1.62e-06        1.62e-05        randomAdd
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However, I do not think that a user queries are the right way for testing such data structures. A data structure that supports graph manipulations and queries in linear time is trivial and not the topic of this question. I am looking for data structures with amortized cost per operation that is sub-linear. The speedup of such sub-linear implementations only manifests for large graphs with thousands of nodes. Benchmark datasets for dynamic graph problems can be found here https://dyngraphlab.github.io/.

Comment: How else would you want to test an implementation?

Comment: It occurred to me that you may have misunderstood how my test application is intended to work.  ( Yesterday's answer was not very clear on this because you had not yet edited your question to clarify what your question was )  So, I have provided an example of how it could be used to measure the responsiveness of a graph engine to graphs of different sizes.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort. However in dynamic graph data structures we are not interested in the time per operation but in the [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) time per operation. Essentially, this means the average runtime per operation over the entire life of the data structure. Measuring the runtime of an individual operation is not meaningful in this context.

Comment: So, you want the average time taken for  multiple executions of a query?  You do understand that due to the extensive caching done by modern machines, executing the same query multiple times goes much faster than a singe query?  Anyway, I have added  timing of multiple edge additions to the application.  Sample run added to my answer.